# Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to type `int` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Space</kbd> to show `int`, `Int16`, `Int32` ...

However it is not showing up, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> it works.

I've tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> as suggested in some places, but nothing changed...

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-assign the Key, or see what's currently assigned to that shortcut by doing the following:

1. Click on `Tools -> Options`.
2. Highlight `Environment -> Keyboard`.
3. Go to the `Press Shortcut Keys` textbox, and type in: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. It will show you what it's currently being used for.
4. If it's not being used for anything, then select: `Edit.CopmpleteWord (Ctrl+Space(TextEditor))`

[image: KeyboardShortcuts Visual Studio]

You can also try to reset Visual Studio's dev settings:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to `Start`, `Run`.
3. Type `cmd`. Press Enter.
   4  Navigate to whatever Visual Studio version you're using (If it's Visual Studio 2008, it's: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0`).
4. Type `devenv /resetsettings`. Press Enter.

> **NB:** Make sure to back up any UI changes you've made to your settings in Visual Studio. This will reset **everything** back to its factory setting.

It's a nuclear option, but it's worked for me when nothing else would.

Comment: I nuked but it won't work. How can I force it to be the same as Ctrl+J ?

Comment: @BrunoLM, I updated my answer to show you how to reassign that shortcut.